# How to properly configure external monitors in Arch with MacBook Pro 11,4

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, xrandr

Dual booting on a MacBook Pro late 2015 model (11,4) works great with arch linux using the Antergos distribution. Though I have two basic issues related to the display resolutions:

1. xrandr settings to not persist after a logout/reboot
2. External monitors break xrandr settings almost every time and sometimes completely lockup and crash my screen making me have to restart

To start, I set the scaling factor for the displays to `1` which seem to be the way to add support for HiDPI screens. Note I have tried with `2` but have similar issues.

I have managed to get the proper xrandr settings with no external monitors by changing the scaling to `1.25` and updating the panning as well. Typically when connecting one external display, it also shows part of my primary screen. I have not yet tried adding my second display (both via the 2 display ports).

Ideally i have one monitor above my laptop screen, and the second is to the right of the first external monitor. I want to try and make a script that runs whenever monitors are unplugged or plugged in to properly set their state, as well as on login. But havent been able to get one to work properly.

I was hoping to see what setups others have accomplished to do this.

Note: I do not have the dedicated GPU, only the Intel chip. I have mostly referenced [HiDPI Settings](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#GNOME) for setting up the the displays as well as [MacBookPro11,x](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBookPro11,x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, as though I was using the current `linux 4.8` kernel which apparently has issues with the intel display drivers. Switching to the `linux-lts 4.4` kernel (also installing the headers) did the trick. Make sure when you do this to either update grub, or your systemd settings which i had to do.

`sudo pacman -S linux-lts linux-lts-headers`

then for systemd I updated the file

```
$ cat /boot/loader/loader.conf
default antergos-lts
```

Which refers to this entry (that I did not have to modify if I recall correctly)

```
$ cat /boot/loader/entries/antergos-lts.conf 
title   Antergos LTS
linux   /vmlinuz-linux-lts
initrd  /initramfs-linux-lts.img
options root=UUID=1aa7683c-f42b-4399-bf63-b4493f40177b rw quiet disable_mode=1
```